# Are these sets compact in $\ell^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Hey everyone I have another analysis question hoping you guys could give me some insight on it. Basically, I am trying to determine whether or not these sets are compact in $\ell^2$.

$$A = \{(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots):|a_n| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\} \\ B=\{(a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots):|a_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}\}$$

(We are assuming the elements in these sets actually belong to $\ell^2$). Anyways I think the first set is not compact since it seems we can find a sequence in here that does not have a converging subsequence. The reason I say this is because of the bound the terms have.

For the second set, I do not even know where to start honestly. I tried to do a diagonalization argument and argue that there is a converging subsequence but failed. I tried showing that every Cauchy sequence in here convergences and we can cover the set by some $\delta$-net, but failed too.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, of course, but Cauchy sequences converging does not imply that our set is compact.

Answer (score 1):

$(1,\frac 1 {\sqrt 2},,...,\frac 1 {\sqrt n},0,0,0,...), n=1,2,3...$ is a  sequence in $A$ . If there is  a subsequence which converges then the limit sequence has to be $(1,\frac 1 {\sqrt 2},,...,\frac 1 {\sqrt n},....)$ but this sequence does not belong to $\ell^{2}$. Hence $A$ is not compact.

$B$ is compact. Given any sequence in $B$ you can use Cantor's diagonal procedure to  extract a  subsequence which conveges coordinatewise. The limiting sequence is in  $\ell^{2}$ because $\sum  \frac 1 {n^{2}} <\infty$. Using the convergence of this series you can show that the subsequence we have obtained converges in the norm of $\ell^{2}$. [I will add more details if necessary].